# Declaracion de una relacion entre 2 modelos en Flask usando sqlAlchemy

Tags: python, flask

Tengo estos dos modelos que los quiero conectar con una relación, sin embargo el primer argumento de db.relationship, es el nombre de la otra tabla a conectarse?
segundo, el backref y el lazy a que se refieren?

```py
   class Users(db.Model):
       id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
       username = db.Column(db.String(length = 30), nullable= False, unique=True)
       email = db.Column(db.String(length= 40), nullable= False, unique= True)
       password = db.Column(db.String(length=60), nullable = False)
       items= db.relationship('Item',backref='owned_user', lazy='true')
```

```py
   class Item(db.Model):
       id = db.Column(db.Integer(),primary_key=True)
       name = db.Column(db.String(length= 30),nullable=False, unique=True)
       barcode = db.Column(db.String(length=12), nullable=False, unique=True)
       price = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
       description = db.Column(db.String(length=1024), nullable=False, unique=True)
       owner = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

El primer argumento es efectivamente el modelo con el cual querés hacer la relación.

El segundo en el nombre de la propiedad que tiene la relación en el modelo con el que queres hacer la relación, en tu caso sería "owner".

El tercer argumento es la marca como debe cargarse los datos de la relación. La opción True es lo mismo que 'select' y significa que la relación se carga cuando se accede a la propiedad.

Este es un ejemplo de la documentación: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many

Aplicada a tu caso creo que debería ser:

```py
class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    ...
    items= db.relationship('Item', backref='owned', lazy='select')

class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    ...
    owner = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```